Experimental design: Formula for D-efficiency/D-error
I've been looking for a software package to create an optimal experimental design for an instance where it's not possible to implement a full factorial design. How optimal a design is can be measured using D efficiency. I've found an 'R' package I wish to use, however the 'D efficiency' values it returns for are very low. My understanding is that D-Efficiency is usually reported on a 0-100% scale, with >80% being considered an acceptable level of D-Efficiency.
The package is reporting "D-efficiency" values well below 10%, even for full factorial designs. There's no help available for the package, but having dug into the details the formula it uses for D efficiency is:
det(M)^(-1/k)
where det(M) is the determinant of the dispersion matrix X'X, and k is the number of parameters.
LinkToCalcDescription
I'm far from an expert on this, but that formula looks like a D-error formula, rather than D-Efficiency (D-Error description). If it is D-Error it would explain why the returned values are so low.
Can someone confirm whether the calculation is indeed returning D-Error?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
